# Installshield 2013 Basic MSI: How to set repair by default during silent install

Tags: installshield

I am currently working on an Installshield 2013 Basic MSI project and am having troubles setting property values during a repair.  After I have installed the program I would like the user to be able to change the values of the properties during a repair.

I have figured out that I cannot set the public property values during a /f repair.

```
msiexec.exe /f project.msi PROPERTY1=VALUE1 PROPERTY2=VALUE2
```

This doesn't work, `PROPERTY1` and `PROPERTY2` will still be set to their default values. I can change the values if I do a /i repair using the UI.

```
msiexec.exe /i project.msi PROPERTY1=VALUE1 PROPERTY2=VALUE2
```

This will set the public properties to the correct values. How can I set the silent install to repair the installation by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've been working on this for a while, and I know someone else might run into the same issues I have been having. Here is the list of steps I had to take to get the msi to install and reinstall with the same command-line /i installer.msi PROP1=Val1 PRRP2=Val2 ... /qn.

1. Add `REINSTALL` to the property table and set it to nothing. If you leave the default value of 0 the installer will error out, because it will try to reinstall a feature called 0.
2. Change the `ReinstallModeText` from `omus` to `vamus`
3. Create a installscript function that will call `MsiSetProperty(hMSI,"REINSTALL","ALL");`
4. Add the function to a Custom Action which will be executed after `AppSearch` where the conditions = `Installed`